# Cannot set width of QLabel at runtime

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing this

```
ui.label->geometry().setWidth(12);
```

However the error I get is

```
Error   1   error C2662: 'QRect::setWidth' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const QRect' to 'QRect &'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometry returns a const QRect reference, so you need to use it like this:

```
QRect r = ui.label->geometry();
r.setWidth(12);
ui.label->setGeometry(r);
```

Or you can use resize:

```
ui.label->resize(12, ui.label->height());
```

But you can also tell us what are you trying to accomplish and maybe we can find a solution that puts the QLabel into a layout and you won't need to manually resize it.

Answer (score 0):

`geometry()` returns you const reference to QRect so it can only be used as read-only information.

Not very beautiful way but you may try calling `setMinimumWidth()`, `setMaximumWidth()` functions with the same desired value as an argument.

Actually resizing label despite it's contents is very suspicious operation)